# Show that $\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k+1}{2\pi}\sin{\left(\frac{2\pi}{2k+1}\right)}\sec{\left(\frac{\pi}{k+2}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, circles, infinite-product, polygons

Show that

$$\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k+1}{2\pi}\sin{\left(\frac{2\pi}{2k+1}\right)}\sec{\left(\frac{\pi}{k+2}\right)}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

**Context:**

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4573539/what-is-the-product-of-the-areas-of-every-regular-polygon-inscribed-in-a-circle?noredirect=1#comment9626409_4573539), I considered the product of the areas of every regular odd-gon inscribed in a circle of area $1$. This is $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k+1}{2\pi} \sin{\frac{2\pi}{2k+1}}=0.18055...$ which I guess does not have a closed form.

On a whim, I divided this number by the [Kepler-Bouwkamp constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonInscribing.html), $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \cos{\frac{\pi}{k+2}}=0.11494...$, and numerical calculation suggests that the result is $\pi/2$.

**My attempt:**

I used the double angle formula for sine to get $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k+1}{\pi}\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2k+1}\right)}\sec{\left(\frac{\pi}{2k+2}\right)}$ but this seems just as intractable as the original form of the product.

Comment: [Polygon circumscribing](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonCircumscribing.html) lists this as identity (9). The included reference seems to be [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1385725865500044).

Comment: The [polygon circumscribing](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonCircumscribing.html) link led me to Wolfram's [sinc function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html) page, which does not lack enthusiasm: it contains the words "interesting property", "remarkable fact", "amazingly", "amazing general result", "spectacular formula"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let

$$K = \prod_{k=3}^\infty \frac1{\cos\left(\frac\pi k\right)}$$

As Bouwkamp points out under *First method* in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1385725865500044),

$$\cos(x) = \frac{\sin(2x)}{2x} \cdot \frac x{\sin(x)} \tag{1}$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
\frac1K &= \prod_{k=3}^\infty \cos\left(\frac\pi k\right) \\[1ex]
&= \prod_{k=3}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}k\right)}{\frac{2\pi}k} \cdot \prod_{k=3}^\infty \frac{\frac\pi k}{\sin\left(\frac\pi k\right)} \tag{1}\\[1ex]
&= \left[\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2k+1}\right)}{\frac{2\pi}{2k+1}} \cdot \prod_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2k}\right)}{\frac{2\pi}{2k}}\right] \cdot \prod_{k=3}^\infty \frac{\frac\pi k}{\sin\left(\frac\pi k\right)} \tag{2}\\[1ex]
&= \left[\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2k+1}\right)}{\frac{2\pi}{2k+1}}\right] \cdot \frac2\pi
\end{align*}$$

where in $(2)$ we split the product over even and odd indices.

Comment: Ah, just a few seconds before me!

Answer (score 3):

Interesting product. Let us define the Kepler-Bouwkamp constant as $c$. Then

$$c=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{k+2}\right)$$

Let $\text{Si}(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$. Then, $\cos(x)=\frac{\text{Si}(2x)}{\text{Si}(x)}$. Plugging this in, we get

$$c=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\text{Si}\left(\frac{2\pi}{k+2}\right)}{\text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{k+2}\right)}$$

Now, observe that every term in the denominator cancels with a term in the numerator because $\frac{\pi}{k+2}=\frac{2\pi}{2(k+1)}$. All that remains is the second term in the numerator and the odd terms of the numerator, viz

$$c=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \text{Si}\left(\frac{2\pi}{2+2}\right)\text{Si}\left(\frac{2\pi}{2k+1}\right)=\text{Si}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\prod_{k=1}^\infty \text{Si}\left(\frac{2\pi}{2k+1}\right)$$

Simplifying, and plugging in the actual product expression for $c$, we have

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{k+2}\right)=\frac{2}{\pi}\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2k+1}{2\pi}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2k+1}\right)$$

Rearranging gives us that $$\frac{\pi}{2}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2k+1}{2\pi}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2k+1}\right)\sec\left(\frac{\pi}{k+2}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

*This one seems to be more difficult than the previous and, for the time being, I am stuck*.

I did not find where was asked
$$P=\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k+1}{\pi}\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2k+1}\right)}$$ for which I post here some ideas.
Consider
$$S=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \log\Bigg[\frac{2k+1}{\pi}\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2k+1}\right)}\Bigg]$$ which, using the series expansion of the logarithm and summing over $k$, write
$$S=\frac 14\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{ ( 2\pi) ^{2 n}\, B_{2 n}\, \zeta \left(2 n,\frac{3}{2}\right)}{n^2\, \Gamma   (2 n)}$$

For the time being, I did not find any closed form but the partial sum converges quite fast as accurately as we wish to
$$S=-1.711744530156267356949288\cdots$$ giving
$$P=0.1805505418498519239123726\cdots$$